# How to get a height of child component?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

trying to make a slider by Vue.js

Have a structure like that

```html
<slider>
    <slide> 1 </slide>
    <slide> 2 </slide>
    <slide> 3 </slide>
</slider>
```

In parent component i've catch the slides through $slots.
В родительском компоненте (slider) получаю слайды через $slots.

There is no problems with a standart *translate* animation. But if i want add a *fade* animation to slides, i have to:

```css
.slider {
position: relative;
}

.slide {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

So, i've to set a height of parent element equal to highest slide.

Trying to do it in mounted hook:

```js
mounted() {

this.slides.forEach((item) => {
  console.log(item.elm.clientHeight);
})

}
```

But it say like:

slide1 height: 1559
slide2 height: 1915
slide3 height: 2371

But real height is:

slide1 height: 431
slide2 height: 315
slide3 height: 347

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mounted hook doesn't guarantee that children will be mounted. I have to set a height in

```js
mounted() {

this.$nextTick(() => {
  // code
})

}
```

Comment: Glad you found a solution!

Answer (score 0):

[MDN is a good resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Determining_the_dimensions_of_elements).

Try this.

```
this.slides.forEach((item) => {
  console.log(item.elm.offsetHeight);
})
```

Comment: The same bug with height